# How can I change the color of the link, remove its underlining and resize it?

Tags: html

I have a link to the site. I need:

1. Change the color to black
2. Change its size and preferably make bold
3. Move it to the center

code:

```
  <p><a href="website">go</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points 1. and 2. are as simple as this:

```
a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px; /* or whatever */
  font-weight: bold; /* or whatever */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

When it comes to centering it you would have to provide more detail about your page structure. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) for more information.

I would suggest googling for a CSS tutorial as these are pretty basic CSS tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
a {
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <p>
    <center>    
        <b>
            <a href="website">go</a>
        </b>
    <center>
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```